# Python/Pandas Rounding numbers on Pivot Table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, rounding

I have been trying to round to 1 or 2 decimal places numbers on a Pivot Table, I have tried both with `df_piv.round(1)` and `np.round(df_piv, 1)`, howere the numbers are still the same.. I have rounded successfully the numbers on the dataframe before creating the pivot however in the pivot the number are not rounded...it seems that I cannot round numbers inside a pivot...is there something else I can do?

EDITED

I have understood, need to convert the number from object to float

Comment: Please share a sample mod pivoted df with expected output.

Comment: Hi @Caiotru! I recommend you to read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and you should provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). With that, some user could help you better.

Comment: Hello, actually by creating a pivot table as an example I can round by 2 or 1 but not with my data...

Comment: Try to provide the example in the question, you can edit it.